# Cant apply Css to my ASP:Label

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I really hope someone can help me with my problem, its freaking me out and its probably a really simple solution :S

I have the following html code:

```
     <body>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
         <asp:Label ID="Game" runat="server" CssClass="logo"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <!---logo ends here -->


        <!--- menu ends here -->
      </div>
      <!---headerends here -->
    </div>
    <!---header-wrapper-ends here -->
    <div id="Title">
.........
</body>
```

and the following css:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#4a4a4a;

}
body {
    background:url(../images/body-bg.jpg);
}

.logo {
    width:380px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0px;

}
.logo h1 {
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

I dont know what im doing wrong here but my ASP label is still showing up as the standard lable with standard font etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try presssing CTRL + F5 on browser

Comment: Probably because you're assigning a width to an inline element (`asp:label` turns into a `<span>` iirc), which by definition is as wide as its content regardless of what you say. Toss a `display:inline-block;` and it should work how you wanted. A warning though, your `div` wrapping the `asp:label` is also selected by `.logo`.

Comment: It will stay the same. The length is working so if you set its width to 5px and type in say "I am the game" It will show "I a" because of the length. If you set the witch to 10000000px or anything it will show "I am the game" the same way as setting to say 30px. You aren't even changing the font so the font will stay normal.

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo h1 {
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

It looks like this block of CSS will select any h1 text inside another tag with a class of .logo. So if you want it to apply to the asp:label, you will need to wrap it in h1 tags, for example:

```
 <div class="logo">
    <h1><asp:Label ID="Game" runat="server" CssClass="logo"></asp:Label></h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: OK. You may have a CSS specificity problem. See [the Specificity page at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more information. Where is your CSS above located?

Comment: Also, to debug specificity issues, you can use the debug capability of your browser to see which rules are being enforced and which are being overridden. If you are using MSIE, for example, press F12, select the HTML tag, and click the Style item on the menu bar. You can drill down through the DOM in the left pane and find your label. The right pane will list all the rules and whether they are applied or not.